# Connect from Virtual Assistant to a Bot which is not a skill

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I have a virtual assistant with skills. I want to connect to another bot which is not deployed as a Skill but only uses Bot V4. Is is possible to connect to the other Bot similar to a Skill?

Comment: I would suggest you to add some minimal demonstration or code snippet to make it more clear to other to get a better and speedy solutions